# "Unable to find a MessageBodyReader" error with multipart request containing a file and JSON

Tags: java, deserialization, quarkus

I have a simple Quarkus application that has a POST resource.

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response updateContent(@MultipartForm MyRequest request) {
    bus.sendAndForget("request", request);
    return Response.accepted().build();
}
```

MyRequest looks like this:

```
public class MyRequest {
  @FormParam("template")
  @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
  private byte[] template;

  @FormParam("data")
  @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  private Map<String, String> data;

  // Default constructor & getters
}
```

I then send the following with Postman:

[image]

I then get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY007545: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader for media type: text&#x2F;plain; charset=us-ascii and class type java.util.Map
```

If I send only the template, it works, so it seems that the JSON string cannot be parsed for some reason.

I think I have all the required dependencies like:

- quarkus-resteasy-jackson
- resteasy-multipart-provider
- resteasy-jackson2-provider

And I have also tried to manually register the ResteasyJackson2Provider, and changing the mediaType of the data property to APPLICATION_JSON, but that didn't help. What am I missing, or am I even sending the JSON properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For form-data there are only file and text fields. Because of this any type will still be interpreted as a text/plain in form-data. However, there's a parameter that you can set in the request filter before it proceeds to parse the data.

Create instance of `ContainerRequestFilter`:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
@Provider
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        // apply next only for your form-data path and ignore all the other requests
        final HttpRequest httpRequest = ResteasyContext.getContextData(HttpRequest.class);
        httpRequest.setAttribute("resteasy.provider.multipart.inputpart.defaultContentType", "application/json");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am very surprised that this is the only way I know of to support JSON in a multipart.